# Docker-compose can't find suitable file, even though it exists

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

So I am running ubuntu 18.04 lts on windows 10 through hyper-v and I'm trying to run the docker compose command through the terminal. When inside the docker folder and I run ls, it says there is a docker-compose.yml file. Still when I run docker compose command, it says no suitable configuration file is found.

```
docker-compose up -d
ERROR: 
    Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
    parent. Are you in the right directory?

    Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml
```

I'm using docker version 18.09.0 and docker compose version 1.22.0

Comment: it's should not be inside of container

Comment: What does your docker-compose.yml file look like?

Answer (score 11):

On Ubuntu Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS I was facing the same issue. I don't know the exact reason but **Docker** and **Docker Compose** installed with snap was not working.

```
sudo snap remove docker && sudo snap remove docker-compose
```

Installed docker from Officials Docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) and compose from [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) via apt and and now my Docker Compose file start working

Comment: On 20.04.3 LTS this is still an issue and is annoying when using docker on a server with different paths. Removing snap is still the best solution.

Comment: It is also an issue on 22.04.1 LTS. Installing docker from the official repo helped. But I had to fix the service file via changing `fd://` to `unix://`. See this [answer](https://forums.docker.com/t/failed-to-load-listeners-no-sockets-found-via-socket-activation-make-sure-the-service-was-started-by-systemd/62505/2) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Found out the problem was using shared folder functionality with Hyper V and windows 10. For some reason docker won't work when the docker-compose.yml file is located inside that, however when I move it outside of the shared(e.g. home directory) folder it does work. So if I want to use the docker file I have to place it outside the shared folder to make it work. Rest of the project runs as expected, so a little workaround ......

Answer (score 2):

Was getting the same error on Ubuntu 20.04. I could not use apt to install docker-compose (Forbidden errors on apt's sources.list and out of my control) so had to install docker-compose with snap

`sudo snap install docker`

That is a "caveat" of docker installed with snap. From docker-snap [README](https://github.com/docker-snap/docker-snap/blob/main/README.md#usage): "All files that docker needs access to should live within your $HOME folder". So that is expected behavior.

Move your project to $HOME folder. For example, I had my project in `/usr/local/src/my_project` and had to move to `~/some_folder/my_project` and then could run `docker-compose`.

Comment: This is the best answer if we are using docker from the snap.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a bit stupid answer I believe but as I am new to using docker desktop on windows. I was trying to run a script file using Ubuntu distro 20.04 LTS. the path I was providing was not correct. because windows user will use path like this in my case `C:\Users\usera\Desktop\Terminology-service\ols` but here when I changed it to  `/mnt/c/Users/usera/Desktop/Terminology-service/ols` it worked.